# consumir webservice a banxico para obtener el tipo de cambio con PHP

Tags: php

Me podrían dar una orientación de como leer el XML que me retorna Banxico o alguna otra opción de como obtener el tipo de cambio Dolares a Pesos al Día

Lo que he intentado realizar es consumir Web Service de Banxico con la Liberia NUSOAP, pd soy nueva en esto ;)

```
url = "http://www.banxico.org.mx/DgieWSWeb/DgieWS?WSDL";
    $client = new nusoap_client($url, 'wsdl');
    $result = $client->call("tiposDeCambioBanxico");
            $xml   = simplexml_load_string($result);
```

El resultado que me muestra es el siguiente, pero no puedo acceder a los Nodos del XML solo me permite acceder al HEADER

```
<header>
    <id>TIPOSDECAMBIO</id>
    <test>false</test>
    <truncated>false</truncated>
    <name xml:lang="sp">Tipos de Cambio</name>
    <prepared>2019-06-05 12:14:07.252</prepared>
    <sender id="BANXICO">
        <name xml:lang="sp">Banco de M�xico</name>
        <contact>
        <name xml:lang="sp">Subgerencia de Desarrollo de Sistemas</name>
        <telephone>(01 55)52372678</telephone>
        </contact>
    </sender>
    <datasetaction>Update</datasetaction>
    <extracted>2019-06-05 12:14:07.252</extracted>
</header>
<bm:dataset>
    <bm:siblinggroup banxico_freq="Dia" time_format="P1D"></bm:siblinggroup>
    <bm:series titulo="Cotizaci�n de las divisas que conforman la canasta del DEG Respecto al peso mexicano Euro" idserie="SF46410" banxico_freq="Dia" banxico_figure_type="TipoCambio" banxico_unit_type="Peso">
        <bm:obs time_period="2019-06-05" obs_value="22.007"></bm:obs>
    </bm:series>
    <bm:series titulo="Cotizaci�n de la divisa Respecto al peso mexicano D�lar Canadiense" idserie="SF60632" banxico_freq="Dia" banxico_figure_type="TipoCambio" banxico_unit_type="Peso">
        <bm:obs time_period="2019-06-05" obs_value="N/E"></bm:obs>
    </bm:series>
    <bm:series titulo="Tipo de cambio                                          Pesos por d�lar E.U.A. Tipo de cambio para solventar obligaciones denominadas en moneda extranjera Fecha de determinaci�n (FIX)" idserie="SF43718" banxico_freq="Dia" banxico_figure_type="TipoCambio" banxico_unit_type="PesoxDoll">
        <bm:obs time_period="2019-06-05" obs_value="19.5418"></bm:obs>
    </bm:series>
    <bm:series titulo="Cotizaci�n de las divisas que conforman la canasta del DEG Respecto al peso mexicano Libra esterlina" idserie="SF46407" banxico_freq="Dia" banxico_figure_type="TipoCambio" banxico_unit_type="Peso">
        <bm:obs time_period="2019-06-05" obs_value="24.8367"></bm:obs>
    </bm:series>
    <bm:series titulo="Cotizaci�n de las divisas que conforman la canasta del DEG Respecto al peso mexicano Yen japon�s" idserie="SF46406" banxico_freq="Dia" banxico_figure_type="TipoCambio" banxico_unit_type="Peso">
        <bm:obs time_period="2019-06-05" obs_value="0.1804"></bm:obs>
    </bm:series>
    <bm:series titulo="Tipo de cambio pesos por d�lar E.U.A. Tipo de cambio para solventar obligaciones denominadas en moneda extranjera Fecha de liquidaci�n" idserie="SF60653" banxico_freq="Dia" banxico_figure_type="TipoCambio" banxico_unit_type="PesoxDoll">
        <bm:obs time_period="2019-06-05" obs_value="19.7609"></bm:obs>
    </bm:series>
</bm:dataset>
```

Comment: Bienvenida a [es.so], te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad. Ah! por cierto, no escribas todo en mayuscula cerrada.

Comment: Adicional a lo que comenta Orlando, por favor incluye en tu pregunta el contenido de $xml cuando ejecutas el código

Comment: @Alfabravo, el contenido de $xml es el segundo bloque de código

Comment: La pregunta sigue en mayúscula sostenida. Sobre el problema accediendo al contenido, lo que buscas leer está en un namespace que no está especificado en el XML. Si revisas los logs, posiblemente haya algo del estilo `PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string(): namespace error : Namespace prefix bm on Envelope is not defined`

Answer (score 1):

Laura. Tal vez lo siguiente es lo que necesitas hacer :

```
$doc->loadXML( $xml );
$XMLresults     = $doc->getElementsByTagName("series");
$output = $XMLresults->item(0)->nodeValue;
```